# Re-write ActiveRecord query in Arel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I just got started with ARel. I'm finding it difficult converting this bit of complex AR query into Arel:

```
    Offer.where(
      "offers.ended_at IS NULL OR offers.started_at < ? AND offers.ended_at >= ?",
      Time.zone.now, Time.zone.now
    )
```

I think having this in Arel will aid readability

Comment: _I think having this in Arel will aid readability_ maybe all opposite (?)

Comment: You don't need to prefix the table name when using its columns, as there are no more tables involved there won't be ambiguous column references. And you can always use your DBMS current timestamp/date function (`Offer.where(ended_at: nil).or(Offer.where('started_at < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND ended_at >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))`)

Comment: @SebastianPalma prefixing can still be a good idea if this is reused and a join is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
offers = Offer.arel_table
offers_with_nil_ended_at = offers[:ended_at].eq(nil)
offers_within_range = offers[:started_at].lt(Time.zone.now).and(
  offers[:ended_at].gteq(Time.zone.now)
)

Offer.where(offers_with_nil_ended_at.or(offers_within_range))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, however, can this be made any clearer? I'm still finding it hard to understand this.

Comment: Yea, I'll re-edit my post using explaining variables

Answer (score 2):

I think using chained scopes would make it more readable too:

```
# in app/models/offer.rb
scope :without_end, -> { where(ended: nil) }
scope :still_valid, -> { where('started_at < :now AND offers.ended_at >= :now', now: Time.current) }
```

And to be used like this:

```
Offer.still_valid.or(Offer.without_end)
```